# f ◦ f = f. Prove that the set S = {x ∈ [0, 1] : f (x) = x} is a closed and bounded interval in [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let f : [0, 1] −→ [0, 1] be a continuous function.

(a) Prove that f has a fixed point, that is, there exists a point c ∈ [0,1] such that
f(c) = c.

(b) Suppose further that f ◦ f = f . Prove that the set S = {x ∈ [0, 1] : f (x) = x} is a
closed and bounded interval in [0,1], that is, S = [a,b] for some 0 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ 1.

For the first part I have already worked out using the Intermediate Value Theorem.

i.e. Let. h(x) = f(x) - x, then plugging in h(1) and h(0).

However,  for the second part of the question it seems like I have not found a adequate arguments towards it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 5):

Defining $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $h(x)=f(x)-x$, we have
$$S=h^{-1}(\{0\}), $$
and since $h$ is continuous, $S$ is closed. Since $S\subset[0,1]$, it is also bounded.

Now, assume $f\circ f=f$. Take $x\in[0,1]$ and set $y=f(x)$. Then,
$$f(y)=f(f(x))=f(x)=y,$$
so $y=f(x)\in S$, for every $x\in[0,1]$. It follows that $f([0,1])\subset S$. Conversely if $y\in S$, then $y=f(y)\in f([0,1])$. Therefore,
$$ f([0,1])=S.$$
Since $f$ is continuous, $f([0,1])=S$ is connected. Since every closed, connected and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed interval, we get the desired result.